# Populate a list in Kotlin with a for loop

Tags: android, list, for-loop, kotlin

It's been a while that I just started to learn how to develop in Kotlin. 
There is this thing that I am working on, I am trying to parse a list into another type of list. Basically they are the same thing but with different names. But when I try to populate the new list with the data that I get from the list given as parameter in the function the list only gets populated with the first object.

Here is my function:

```
fun convertRoomClass(course: List<Course>) : List<Courses> {

    lateinit var list : List<Courses>


    course.forEach {
        val id = it.pathID
        val name = it.pathName
        val desc = it.pathDescription

        val crs : Courses = Courses(id, name!!, desc!!)

         list = listOf(crs)
    }

    return list
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The error in your code is that you are making a list in every iteration of the loop. You should make the list first and then add every item from the loop to it!

```
fun convertRoomClass(courses: List<Course>) : List<AnotherCourseClass> {
    val newList = mutableListOf<AnotherCourseClass>()
    courses.forEach {
        newList += AnotherCourseClass(it.pathID, it.pathName, it.pathDescription)
    }
    return newList
}
```

A better solution is to use the map function

```
fun convertRoomClass(courses: List<Course>) = courses.map {
   AnotherCourseClass(it.pathID, it.pathName, it.pathDescription)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You might be looking for Kotlin [Map](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/map.html)

**Example:**

```
course.map { Courses(it.pathID, it.pathName,it.pathDescription) }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're getting the list with only on object, cause the function `listOf(crs)` returns a list of all objects that are passed as a parameters. Saying the same thing in `Java` you're doing something like this:

```
for (course: Courses) {
    Course course = new Course(...);
    List<Course> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(course);
    return list;
}
```

As you can see the it created new list with a single object per iteration.
What you're trying to achieve, can be done with operator `map{...}` which simply transforms every object in the initial list using code passed inside `map` and returns list of transformed objects

```
course.map{ Courses(...) }
```

Also, I've noticed that you're using the `!!` operator when creating a `Courses` object. Probably because the `Course` can have `nullable` name, while `Courses` can't. I'm considering this as a bad practice, cause in this case you're saying

> Please throw an `Exception` if the name is `null`.

I think that a much better approach is to provide an alternative, like:

`val name = course.name ?: "default"`, saying

> Please use `name` or `"default"` if the `name` is `null`.

or skip objects without name, or any other approach that suits your situation.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer and the suggestions :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use [MutableList](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-list/index.html) instead of List. That enable you to append new element at the end of your list instead of replace the entire list by doing : `list = listOf(crs)`

So replace the type of your var `lateinit var list : List<Courses>` by `lateinit var list : MutableList<Courses>` then replace `list = listOf(crs)` by `list.add(crs)`

Hope it helps and have fun :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad you find out a solution :)